# Downloading large areas of OpenStreetMap data with QGIS OSM plugin?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, mac

I have OpenStreetMap data loading failure problem. I want to use the Download OpenStreetMap data tool in QGIS. I want to select the extent from map canvas like shown below:

[image].

For me, the osm-data usually works when the data downloaded map was less then 1:160000 scale. But when it is bigger than 1:320000 scale (including 1:320000), QGIS always gets infinite loading circle rainbow (OS X user).

Does anyone have an idea on how to get it to work?

GIS Software : QGIS
Hardware : Mac
OS : OS X 10.9.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QGIS and the server behind Overpass API are not able to handle large area requests.

If you need that amount of data, think about

- downloading pbf extracts from Geofabrik
- filter the data for the items you really want with direct Overpass API calls
- set up a local postgis database for your area of interest with a suitable Geofabrik extract

Comment: As you told me about extracted pbf, I tried to load it by adding new vector layers but, it doesn't work with multi polygons, multilinestrings and lines. Any Idea ?  Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Polygons are yet an issue, but lines should be imported. You have to select the layers you want by clicking them. Start with a small extract, as QGIS has to keep everything in RAM. Using a postgis database is the best way to get all polygons the way they are rendered in mapnik, even for larger areas. But I have no experience with Postgis on Mac.